# MySQL select records using MAX(datefield) minus three days

Tags: mysql, select, max, date-range

Clearly, I am missing the forest for the trees...I am missing something obvious here!

Scenario:

I've a typical table `asset_locator` with multiple fields:

```
id, int(11) PRIMARY
logref, int(11)
unitno, int(11)
tunits, int(11)
operator, varchar(24)
lineid, varchar(24)
uniqueid, varchar(64)
timestamp, timestamp
```

---

My current challenge is to SELECT records from this table based on a date range. More specifically, a date range using the MAX(timestamp) field. 
So...when selecting I need to start with the latest timestamp value and go back 3 days.

EX: I select all records WHERE the `lineid` = 'xyz' and going back 3 days from the latest timestamp. Below is an actual example (of the dozens) I've been trying to run. 
MySQL returns a single row with all NULL values for the following:

```
SELECT id, logref, unitno, tunits, operator, lineid, 
        uniqueid, timestamp, MAX( timestamp ) AS maxdate
FROM asset_locator 
WHERE 'maxdate' < DATE_ADD('maxdate',INTERVAL -3 DAY)
ORDER BY uniqueid DESC
```

There MUST be something obvious I am missing. If anyone has any ideas, please share. 
Many thanks!

Comment: latest timestamp value for all records or a single asset record?

Comment: Lets say max is 10 january you want where 10 january<7january which doesnt make sense,you want BETWEN DATE ADD.... AND MAX

Comment: The usage will actually include an additional condition when in production, "WHERE lineid='xyz' "  So, to answer xQbert, only selecting timestamp value(s) for records matching the given `lineid` value.

Answer (score 3):

MAX() is an aggregated function, which means your SELECT will always return one row containing the maximum value. Unless you use GROUP BY, but it looks that's not what you need.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max

If you need all the entries between MAX(timestamp) and 3 days before, then you need to do a subselect to obtain the max date, and after that use it in the search condition. Like this:

```
SELECT id, logref, unitno, tunits, operator, lineid, uniqueid, timestamp
FROM asset_locator
WHERE timestamp >= DATE_ADD( (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM asset_locator), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
```

It will still run efficiently as long as you have an index defined on `timestamp` column.

Note: In your example

```
WHERE 'maxdate' < DATE_ADD('maxdate',INTERVAL -3 DAY)
```

Here you were are actually using the string "maxdate" because of the quotes causing the condition to return false. That's why you were seeing NULL for all fields.

Edit: Oops, forgot the "FROM asset_locator" in query. It got lost at some point when writing the answer :)

Comment: Thank you FlyLo11!!! - This was the approach I was looking for. BTW, for future readers... the above SELECT statement has a small hiccup: it also requires the initial "FROM asset_locator" ahead of the WHERE clause where the sub_select resides:                                                 SELECT id, logref, unitno, tunits, operator, lineid, uniqueid, timestamp FROM asset_locator WHERE timestamp >= DATE_ADD( ( SELECT MAX( timestamp ) FROM asset_locator ) , INTERVAL -7 DAY ); –